# How to "Filter" the Information from a Table and Display into Another Table?

Tags: excel

**Scenario:** One student can register any amount of subjects and one subject can be registred by any amount of students. I have two tables for these information:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4tGp.png) **records** all the subjects registered by each of the student.

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2iTR.png) **displays** all the students name registered for each of the subjects.

For Table 1, I can manually add the subjects registered by each of the student into the columns "Subject" (starting from Column B and so on).
Then, the result has to be updated and displayed in Table 2. The result should be the same as shown in the screenshot here: [Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2iTR.png)

I tried to use this formula: `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Table 1'!A:A,'Table 1'!B:B=A2))` in Sheet `Table 2` Cell `B2` but it can only display the correct result if the particular subject are all in the same column. May I know how to improve this formula or are there any better solution(s) for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Microsoft 365 you can use `FILTER()` function with `MMULT()`. Try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER($A$2:$A$5,MMULT(--($B$2:$F$5=H2),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS($B$2:$F$2)))))
```

[image]